# Change date if the hour is after after midnight

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a really new programmer. I'm trying to write something that automatically puts the date on my sheets. If the time is after midnight and still not 6AM I want the previous day's date. Is this possible?

This is what I have so far; I'm stuck:

```js
var CueectHoure = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Asia/Jerusalem", "HH");
var CurrectDay = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Asia/Jerusalem", "dd");
var CurrectMunth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Asia/Jerusalem", "MM");
var FullDay = CurrectDay + "." + CurrectMunth;
var fulldayless = CurrectDay -1 + "." + CurrectMunth;
var dayplus = CurrectDay - 31;
Browser.msgBox(dayplus);

// check if the hour is above 00 and under 6
if (CueectHoure > 00 & CueectHoure <= 6){

  //what happens if date is 1.11? we need return to 31.10        
  if (CurrectDay == 1){  
         CurrectDay = CurrectDay -1; // stuck here
  } else {

  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('n1').setValue(FullDay);
  Browser.msgBox(FullDay);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Instead of substract 1, substract 86400000 and use the result to get a new Date object.

## Explanation

Google Sheets and Google Apps Script use different units for datetime values. While one day is the unit on Google Sheets, on Google Apps Script is one millisecond.

## Code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(today - oneDay);
  Logger.log('Today: %s', today.toLocaleDateString());
  Logger.log('Yesterday: %s', yesterday.toLocaleDateString());
}
```

## Logs

```
[16-10-30 19:05:08:315 CST] Today: October 30, 2016
[16-10-30 19:05:08:315 CST] Yesterday: October 29, 2016
```